# Code Timing/Automating Javascript

Tags: javascript, benchmarking

I'm currently doing GCSE Computing (so I'm not so clued up) and am trying to make a traffic light program which is automated and requires no user input. I have a code for a traffic light program already but it requires the user to press a button in order for the lights to change (this was the first part of the task) but am now like a rabbit in headlights with using timings. How do I do this? What kind of keywords do I need? What kind of structure? I'm really quite clueless. I've researched it but it doesn't make any sense to me.
It's probably a really easy thing, but I'm stuck.
Thanks

Comment: Google setInterval.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` or `setTimeout` in Javascript, this way you can have multiple set's of traffic lights, and alternate the lights status between them in certain routines. You can use this for a starting point in your coursework:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp